# add post id or slug via php on funciton.php

Tags: php, wordpress

i want to add custom field to post automatically so i have this code on theme function.php

```
add_action('publish_post', 'add_custom_field_automatically');

function add_custom_field_automatically($post_ID) {

global $wpdb;

if(!wp_is_post_revision($post_ID)) {

    add_post_meta($post_ID, 'test', 'text . $slug . text', true);

}
```

all works but value of custom field  is plain text:
     text . $slug . text

i want to be  TEXT + id or slug of post + TEXT

so that variable $slug is not working and script add it as plain text

Answer (score 0):

fixed by changing this line to

```
        add_post_meta($post_ID, 'test', "text '. $post_ID .' text", true);
```